# Загрузка файла на файловый обменник

Tags: python, requests

подскажите как загрузить файл на файловый обменник? например на: [imgur.com/upload](https://imgur.com/upload) или любой другой файловый обменник,
по итогу хочу получить страницу с загруженным файлом, чтобы спарсить и получить прямую ссылку на фото.
Пытался двумя вариантами, но не выходит. По возможности, решение нужно без регистрации и api.
Первая проба:

```
import requests
files = {"file-input": ("/test/1111.png", open("/test/1111.png", "rb"))}
r = requests.post("https://imgur.com/upload", files=files)
print(r.text)
```

вторая проба:

```
import requests
multiple_files = [
    ('images', ('/test/1111.png', open('/test/1111.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))
]
resp = requests.post('https://imgur.com/upload', files=multiple_files)
print(resp.text)
```

Поискав кучу хостингов изображений, понял что `json` уже отходит. И наверно без `selenium` не обойтись. Чтобы просто имитировать нажатия и после спарсить прямую ссылку. Не понял только как в ней понять, что файл загружен успешно и можно парсить ссылку?

Comment: у `imgur` есть `api` и библиотека под питон `https://apidocs.imgur.com`

Comment: @n1tr0xs Это решение. Но я ищу решение без регистрации пользователя, так как пользователи скрипта будут загружать много разных изображений, плюс хранить их достаточно всего час или даже минут 30. А если например возможность проделать загрузку на этот сайт (это где я планировал использовать изображение) https://imagereverse.io, или тут тоже только через api? Или же поискать другой файловый обменник с получением прямой ссылки на загруженное изображение?

Answer (score 1):

Можна попробовать использовать `file.io`, в целом Ваше решение сохранится (я лишь немного изменил его структуру) и не нужно будет использовать `API` или производить регистрацию. Загруженные файлы хранятся `14 дней`, возможно есть и другие ограничения, но я сильно тестированием не занимался, лишь проверил на нескольких фотографиях :)

```python
import requests

file_path = "/test/1111.png"
url = "https://file.io/"

with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    files = {'file': file}
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)

response_json = response.json() # Это обший вывод, там пишется статус загрузки, что загружается и все такое, можете потестировать print(response_json), если Вам это нужно.
file_link = response_json.get('link', 'No link found') # Вывод конкретно ссылки на загруженный файл.
print(file_link)
```

Успехов в Ваших проектах :)

Comment: вариан хороший, спасибо. Но мне нужно прямую ссылку на изображение - иными словами, чтобы на конце ссылки был формат изображерия, то есть, если загружу ссылку я сразу увижу изображение.